# Reply to message as threaded response in MS Teams using Azure Bot Sevices

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, rest

I have been referring to docs like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#reply-to-activity) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to send a reply to a proactive message as threaded message.

But, I am only able to send each message as independent message and not as reply message.

I want to have a reply like this: 
[image]

I am pretty sure the channel allows reply, since the screenshot is from the channel itself.

My request payload :
URL:https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}
Method: POST

```html
{
  "type": "message",
  "from": {
    "id": "bot-id",
    "name": "bot name"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "19:channelId",
    "name":"random name"
  },
   "recipient": {
        "id": "recepientId",
        "name": "name"
    },
  "text":"I want to reply to threadid",
  "replyToId":"{activityId}"
}
```

This is supposed to be very simple, but I am struggling to find what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the URL Like this:

```
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/{channelId;messageid={activityId}/activities
```

and it worked like  a charm!

Comment: How did you know to use that URL? After looking at the documentation for hours, I've never seen it mentioned. Anywhere. It's super frustrating.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0&preserve-view=true @Anthony

Comment: @druveen I don't see an explanation of this format on the page: `{channelId;messageid={activityId}`

Comment: @Anthony I feel there is a typo in the below URL,
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/{channelId;messageid={activityId}/activities


"To send the reply, issue this request:
POST /v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId} "

is what the below link says 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0&preserve-view=true